# UDP communication to device that responds to port request comes from, how to get that response

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, udp

I'm currently attempting to receive device information via `UDP`.

I will be using `<broadcast` as I do not know the IP of the unit(s).

Having never done any `UDP` communication before, I created a basic `listener.py`:

```
import socket

if __name == "__main__":
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = 6137

    inbound = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    inbound.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        data, wherefrom = inbound.recvfrom(1024, 0)
        data = struct.unpack("!L3i", data)
        data = str(data)
        sys.stderr.write(repr(wherefrom) + "\n")
        sys.stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout.write(data + "\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

And a `broadcast.py`:

```
from socket import *
import struct

def broadcast():

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        UDP_IP = '<broadcast>'
        UDP_PORT = 6137
        HEX = 0x2F03F4B2
        I = 0
        V = 0
        C = 0
        PAYLOAD = struct.pack("!L3i", HEX, I, V, C)
        comsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) 
        comsocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        comsocket.sendto(PAYLOAD, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
        comsocket.close()
```

If I run the `listener.py` and then run the `broadcast.py` I see that the message was sent, and it's correctly unpacked at the other end.

The problem I've having is that when I send this broadcast (above is a modified version of what I would actually be sending), the devices are meant to send back a response, to the same `port` where the broadcast comes from.

So this is where I'm stuck, I know I can `socket.bind()` to force my broadcast to send from a fixed port, hence the device(s) will be responding to that same port but if I `bind` it I can't run my `listener.py` on the same port, obviously.

How do I go about receiving the response sent to a port that I choose using a 'bound broadcast'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket can send and receive. Also if it is udp and bound to a port. You can send a message back to the broadcasting socket.

```
# broadcast.py
from socket import *
import struct

if __name__ == "__main__":
        UDP_IP = '<broadcast>'
        UDP_PORT = 6139
        HEX = 0x2F03F4B2
        I = 0
        V = 0
        C = 0
        PAYLOAD = struct.pack("!L3i", HEX, I, V, C)
        comsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) 
        comsocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        comsocket.sendto(PAYLOAD, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
        data, wherefrom = comsocket.recvfrom(1024, 0)
        print data, wherefrom
        comsocket.close()
```

This is the listener that sends back to the broadcasting socket:

```
import socket
from socket import *
import struct
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = 6139

    inbound = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    inbound.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        data, wherefrom = inbound.recvfrom(1024, 0)
        data = struct.unpack("!L3i", data)
        data = str(data)
        sys.stderr.write(repr(wherefrom) + "\n")
        sys.stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout.write(data + "\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        inbound.sendto('lala', wherefrom)
        print wherefrom
```

Comment: This would be my ailing memory failing me. It's been 12 years since university and sockets, I really should have remembered that! Much appreciated.